# Drupal: building a users-submitted testimonials page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the easiest way to create a testimonial page in Drupal ?

I need the users be able to add a comment on the bottom of the page, and I need to approve them before they can be published.

I could use views + webform module for it ? Or is there something simpler ?

thanks

Comment: @ Patrick I just thought about it some more. The built-in Comments module works for making comments on nodes. Are you just trying to adapt that functionality to a view?

Comment: @Jake yeah I thought about that, but I want my users to be able to write into 2 fields (Name and Content) without registering to the website. Also, not sure if I can approve comments or not.. can I ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a content type called "Testimonials" and set it to default Unpublished. Call the Title field "Name" and the body field "Testimonial".

Create a View called testimonials with a page attachment that lists out nodes of type "testimonial" with a filter for Published = Yes. Set the path to "/testimonials".

Use the Form Block module (http://drupal.org/project/formblock) to put the Node Add form for the Testimonial content page into a block.

Configure the block you created to appear at the bottom of the testimonial page (your theme should have a "Content bottom" region, if not you'll need to add one by editing the theme's page.tpl.php and $theme.info file.

To approve a testimonial, go to the content list, filter by Type: Testimonial and Status: Unpublished then use the checkboxes and the drop-down to change the status to "Published".

This will provide a page that lists testimonials, with an "add testimonial" form at the bottom of the page, and all testimonials must be approved before they will appear on the site.

Comment: It seems perfect, I just have one issue with formblock. Only the node title field appear in the block. How can I add the other CCK fields as well ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your criteria for a testimonial is just a block of text then creating a "testimonial" content type would work. You could allow users to create them but require admin approval to be published.

You can also change the [access control for comment approval](http://drupal.org/node/258156)

---

Edit:

This was going to be my follow-up comment when you clarified that you wanted a form at the bottom of an existing page.

> I don't know if this works, but try
>   viewing the HTML source of
>   `/node/add/testimonial` in your
>   browser and copy everything from
>   `<form action="/node/add/page"...` to
>   the closing `</form>` tag.

Gah. That sounds hideously complicated. If you want a form at the **bottom** of an existing page then maybe the plugin you mentioned is the best option (but I haven't researched it).

Comment: mhm ok, how can I add the "Create Testimonial" page on the bottom of my view ?

Comment: Give the guests the right to add testimonial content type and as the footer html for that view, add a link to testimonial creation page (or insert a form that posts to the node/create)

Comment: @Patrick Yeah, what Ege said. Create a link in the footer of your view and have it go to `/node/add/testimonial`.

Comment: @Ege Özcan and @Jake Sorry if I misunderstood, but my question is how to directly embed the creation page on the bottom of the view. Not just add a link to it. thanks